# Vuejs _.orderBy is not sorting the json

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, lodash

**UPDATE**
   Below is the json which I get through API using axios.

```
 bannerData= [
        {
          "id": 118,
          "title": "Geruchsbel\u00e4stigung",
          "location": "DOR",
          "pressInformation": [
            {
                "id": 257,
                "title": "Chemi257"
              },
              {
               "id": 256,
               "title": "Chemi256",
              }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 144,
          "title": "Testing Stage",
          "location": "LEV",
          "pressInformation": [
            {
              "id": 254,
               "title": "Chemi254",
            },
            {
              "id": 261,
               "title": "Chemi261",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

```js
computed: {
    orderedUsers: function() {
      this.secondSubBanner = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.bannerData.length; i++) {
        this.subBanner = this.bannerData[i].pressInformation;
        for (let j = 0; j < this.subBanner.length; j++) {
          this.secondSubBanner.push(this.subBanner[j].id);
          console.log(this.secondSubBanner); // output: 257, 256, 254,261
        }
      }
      return this.secondSubBanner;
    },
```

```
sortedArray() {
      let v = this.orderedUsers.sort();
      console.log(v); // output: 254, 256, 257, 261
      return _.orderBy(this.bannerData, v)
    }
```

sortedArray is printing the id's in order using sort(). But it cannot sort the Json properites depends using `_.orderBy()`. Can anyone say where I have done the mistake?

Comment: Isn't `_.orderBy()` an Undersore / Lo-Dash function?

Comment: Yes, it is a lodash function and I have imported the lodash library `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"/>`

Comment: What does `bannerData` look like? Why are you passing `v` as the second parameter to `orderBy`?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: @SreenivasuluGudipati What's the desired output after sorting of yours?

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh, My desired output is Chemi254 Chemi256 Chemi257 Chemi261 Now I am getting Chemi257 Chemi256 Chemi254 Chemi261

Comment: @SreenivasuluGudipati Try the answer I gave below to see if it's what you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this algorithm. I think with what you want, you don't need `lodash`. I only used `flatMap()` and `sort()` built-in to get this:

```js
function sortedArray(bannerData) {
  const array = bannerData.flatMap(x => x.pressInformation)
  return array.sort( (a,b) => a.id - b.id )
}

bannerData = [
  {
    "id": 118,
    "title": "Geruchsbel\u00e4stigung",
    "location": "DOR",
    "pressInformation": [
      {
        "id": 257,
        "title": "Chemi257"
      },
      {
        "id": 256,
        "title": "Chemi256",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 144,
    "title": "Testing Stage",
    "location": "LEV",
    "pressInformation": [
      {
        "id": 254,
        "title": "Chemi254",
      },
      {
        "id": 261,
        "title": "Chemi261",
      }
    ]
  }
]

console.log(sortedArray(bannerData))
```

Comment: @Sreenivasulu Gudipati Did this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you very much. your logic would obviously be the solution, but the 'dataBanner' here produces the sorting of the objects that are inside the 'pressInformation'. When I render using 'v-for="events in dataBanner"' loop, I can render only the objects inside the 'pressInformation'. I also need to access the properties like 'location' inside the same v-for loop which is not being possible..

Comment: I'm not sure what's the specific context of your problem, but it smells the wrong strategy design in the first place. At the end of the day if this answer somehow *obviously is the solution* of the question you have put, please considering accept it.

Comment: Ofcourse I accept your answer, it helped me. it is very much thinner than my fat functions. 

I have to find a method to render the `location` property in the same v-for loop of your  `console.log(sortedArray(bannerData))`

Comment: @SreenivasuluGudipati Hope you'll solve your problem quickly

Comment: `bannerData.map(x => x.prop).flat()` can be simplified to `bannerData.flatMap(x => x.prop)`